# Do iOS App Short Links Take a While to Activate?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I know that once your app is ready for sale, it can take a while to propagate to all of Apple's servers. Is the same thing true of short links of the form `http://appstore.com/myapp`?

I can find my application on the store through search, and it can be downloaded. Direct links using the Application ID lead to the app perfectly. However, using the short link created following the directions [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1633/_index.html) gives me an "Item not Found" error.

My app has been up for about 7 hours. This is rather important, because I use the short link from within the app to invite new users.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it does indeed take a few hours for Apple to link the short URL to the full one. In my case, it took 12 hours.